# How to run a file in controller continuously in CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm working on CI framework,where I need to run one file in controller continuously to check the data in the database.
I have tried that by refreshing the page for every 2 seconds in PHP. But it doesn't seems like best approach to do that to load the entire page for every 2 seconds. So I'm trying to run that file through ajax call.
Normally in php I can able to do run the file continuously. I tried the same in this framework, but I'm getting some error like **'Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in system/expressionengine/controllers/popup.php** because of class in controller.
Is there any way to run the file in controller continuously through AJAX call.

Here is my code

```html
<?php
class Popup extends CI_Controller 
{
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('popup_model');
 }
 public function popup1()
 {
  $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  $sec = "2";
  header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
  $data['popup'] = $this->popup_model->get_events();
  $data['title'] = 'Pop Up';
  if (empty($data['popup']))
  {
   
  }
  else
  {
   $this->load->view('popup/popup1',$data);
   $this->load->view('popup/eve',$data);
  }
}

}
```

Comment: What `URL` you are trying to access in your ajax call??

Comment: here i'm calling like this  

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
       
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "popup.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        setTimeout(showHint, 1000);

Comment: Use `jquery ajax` it's quite easy to do this and what you are trying to do in popup.php?? You should create controller and view for that but first update your question with code of popup.php.

Comment: the posted code is popup.php , it is controller .

Comment: Now simply change your ajax url to `xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://yourdomainname/popup/popup1", true); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a ajax call into the one function and on document ready pass that function to the javascript function as `setInterval(functionname, interval_delay);`

Answer (score 0):

Every 2 Seconds one AJAX call is not good and may overload your server with too many requests. There are other alternatives like PHPWebsockets and NodeJS to achieve this.

Comment: I don't have any idea about PHPWebsockets and NodeJS. Can you suggest me any example for this.

Comment: Yes Sure
Following links you can use.
http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html
https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/
http://www.nodebeginner.org/
http://arminboss.de/blog/2013/tutorial-how-to-create-a-basic-chat-with-node-js/

Following links I have used to learn nodejs and phpwebsockets. This can be tricky at start but is very efficient in current case